# Answer UP voted points are not getting reflected

Tags: bug

**[My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747543/locationlistener-of-network-provider-is-enabled-but-onlocationchanged-is-never/19282976#19282976)** got 4 UP votes, but i didn't got any reputation changes for it.

Answer (score 3):

That is because the question is made *Community Wiki*. And all answers automatically are *CW* too. You don't get rep for those posts.

> Community Wiki posts work by transferring ownership of the post from the original author to the community. They make the post easier to edit and maintain by a wider group of users, but **they do not contribute to any user's reputation**.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)